# Auto-updating model list with custom sorting

Tags: sorting, ember.js, ember.js-4

I am trying to apply custom sorting to the models; however, using the [`sort` computed property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/sort) is sorting the models on the initial load of the page but it is not auto-updating the page when more models are entered into the store.

- Ember-Source: 4.7.0
- Ember-Data: 4.7.3
- Ember-CLI: 4.6.0
- Ember-CLI-Typescript: 2.4.0

`app/models/item.ts`:

```js
import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class Item extends Model {
  @attr('string')
  declare name: string;
}

// DO NOT DELETE: this is how TypeScript knows how to look up your models.
declare module 'ember-data/types/registries/model' {
  export default interface ModelRegistry {
    'item': Item;
  }
}
```

`app/routes/index.ts`:

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { service } from '@ember/service';
import type Store from '@ember-data/store';

export default class Index extends Route {
  @service
  declare store : Store;

  async model(){
    return this.store.peekAll('item');
  }
}
```

`app/controllers/index.ts`:

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { sort } from '@ember/object/computed';
import Item from 'sorting-test/models/item';

const sortNumeric = (a: Item, b: Item) => parseInt(a.id, 10) - parseInt(b.id, 10);

export default class Index extends Controller {
  @sort("model", sortNumeric)
  declare sortedModels: Item[]
}

// DO NOT DELETE: this is how TypeScript knows how to look up your controllers.
declare module '@ember/controller' {
  interface Registry {
    'index': Index;
  }
}
```

`app/templates/index.hbs`:

```
{{@model.length}}:{{this.sortedModels.length}}
```

`tests/acceptance/index-test.ts`:

```js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, settled } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import type Store from '@ember-data/store';

module('Acceptance | index', function (hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);

  test('visiting /', async function (assert) {
    const store = this.owner.lookup('service:store') as Store;

    await visit('/');

    assert.equal(this.element.textContent, '0:0');

    store.createRecord('item', {id: '10', name: 'A'});
    store.createRecord('item', {id: '2', name: 'B'});

    await settled();
    assert.equal(this.element.textContent, '2:2');
  });
});
```

Passes the first assertion but the second assertion fails with:

> ```
> actual: > 2:0
> expected: > 2:2
> ```

I have tried changing the line `@sort("model", sortNumeric)` to use different combinations of `model.[]`, `model.@each`, `model.@each.id` but none of them seem to have any effect.

How do get the template to auto-update with custom sorting? (and is this a reoccurrence of https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/19101)?

Comment: This passes the acceptance test in Ember 4.3 and 4.6 (not tested other 4.X releases) but appears to break in Ember 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

Change the controller to use a native getter rather than the `sort` computed property:

```js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import Item from 'sorting-test/models/item';

const sortNumeric = (a: Item, b: Item) => parseInt(a.id, 10) - parseInt(b.id, 10);

export default class Index extends Controller {
  // Declare the model otherwise typescript raises errors.
  declare model: Item[];

  get sortedModels(){
    // Copy the array otherwise sort will try to re-order it in place and fail.
    return this.model.slice().sort(sortNumeric);
  }
}

// DO NOT DELETE: this is how TypeScript knows how to look up your controllers.
declare module '@ember/controller' {
  interface Registry {
    'index': Index;
  }
}
```